# How to cherry-pick a branch that contains merges

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

We develop new features in feature branches that branch off `master`. Sometimes, such features shall be back-ported to a previous version of the software, and we'd like that preferably with the history intact.

I understand that I can use `git cherry-pick A..B` to pick the range of commits. However, long lived feature branches might contain merges to keep them up to date with master. When encountering merge commits, cherry-pick aborts.

Is there some (preferably canonical) way to do so? Something like

```
git cherry-pick --ignore-merges master...feature
```

For reference, the branch setup looks somewhat like this. I'd like to cherry-pick the commits H, K and K from my feature branch, into version_old.

```
A - B - C - D - E - L [master]
|       \       \
|        H - J - M - K [feature]
\
 F - G [version_old]
```

Comment: You can provide multiple commit range and many individuals commit as well. will not that work for you?

Comment: @BittuChoudhary That would work, but it's rather tedious and error prone for feature branches with many commits and merges.  Compiling the list of commits in the correct order, removing merges, then passing the list to cherry-pick also seems somewhat cumbersome for something as "easy" as "add that feature to this other branch".  Which is why I was hoping for a more straight-forward solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git log --pretty=%H --reverse --no-merges A..B | git cherry-pick --stdin
```

Comment: For complex cases, this is probably the right way to handle it. Essentially we use `git rev-list` (`git log --pretty=%H` is basically `git rev-list` in disguise), which has all the control knobs we might want—including `--first-parent`—then read the final list of commits to cherry-pick from stdin (for some reason `--stdin` is not listed in the options in the documentation, though it is in one of the *examples*...). I suspect, however, that one may find that in complex commit graphs the cherries to be picked will often fit poorly if at all by the time we reach the latest commits.

Comment: @torek Thanks for your insightful comment as usual. I've made some tests. Git-rebase seems able to do the job too. But it's a bit more tricky and I have not found an elegant and neat procedure yet. The refs used in git-rebase are always a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I tried few options with cherry-pick and i think this one is what you're looking for

```
git cherry-pick ^J H..K
```

It will cherry-pick all commits between H and K excluding J.
Read [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#git-cherry-pick-codegitcherry-pickHEADmastercode)

Comment: You can try passing range in exclusion.

Comment: This does not quite work in general.  The problem is that `H..K` "means" `K ^H` so this is `^J K ^H`: get me everything reachable from `J`, excluding everything reachable from `J`, excluding everything reachable from `H`. If `H` is an ancestor of `J`, the `^H` is redundant. In this particular example we also pick up commits on both sides of merge `M` (i.e., `D` and `E`), which is perhaps not desirable. Note that `B` and `C` are excluded by virtue of being reachable from `H` and `J`.

Comment: (Er, that should read "everything reachable from *`K`*, excluding [things reachable from J and H]".  Typos, discovered 16 hours later, sigh.)

Comment: Thanks @torek , i missed reading [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#git-cherry-pick-codegitcherry-pickmaintnextmastercode) .